# How to use hping natively or with fork in C?

Tags: c, hping

Searched via google a lot about this question but I can't figure out a solution for this.
I am trying to implement an MPI portscanner using the gnu c hping library.
Only problem is, the hping homepage is down, and the usage is for shell only.
I want to use hping to check if a port is open or closed (three-way-tcp handshake successful or not).

Are there any examples for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute hping and parse its output. Algorythm is simple:

1. Use pipe() to create one-directional pipe
2. Use fork() to create another process
3. In child process:
4. Use dup2() to substitute stdout by output end of pipe. Don't forget to close input end of pipe.
5. Use execlp() to execute hping
6. In parent process:
7. hping output would be available in input end of pipe. Don't forget to close output end of pipe.

Comment: Do i really need a pipe to get the return value of hping accessable in the main prog? Basically i have no idea of piping (except usage of pipes in bash). Another problem is that i have no idea what the return value basically is.

Comment: You can call hping via system("hping > results.txt") and parse results.txt file.

Comment: Have one more question but i don't want to open up another silly question. I piped the output of hping3 to my parent process but when i read the pipe theres no output.

Comment: Seems like there are some issues with hping3 and the output redirection according to posts i found on the net.
( hping3 10.1.1.1 -c 1 -q ) >/filepath/filename should work, but is not tested yet

Comment: I don't know how hping3 works, but I assume he may print it's data via stderr.